# Open a folder with the window maximized

Tags: c#

I have this method that works ok:

```
 private static void OpenFolder(string fileName)
    {

        var fol= new ProcessStartInfo("Explorer.exe", "/select," + fileName);
        Process.Start(fol);
    }
```

But how could I set the new opening window to maximized? I see the WindowStyle property but not WindowState.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WindowStyle` is what you will have to use, add the following line before starting the process.

```
 fol.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
```

From MSDN:

> > **Hidden:**   The hidden window style. A window can be either visible or hidden. The system displays a hidden window by not drawing it. If a window is hidden, it is effectively disabled. A hidden window can process messages from the system or from other windows, but it cannot process input from the user or display output. Frequently, an application may keep a new window hidden while it customizes the window's appearance, and then make the window style Normal. To use ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, the ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute property must be false.
> >
> > **Maximized**:    The maximized window style. By default, the system enlarges a maximized window so that it fills the screen or, in the case of a child window, the parent window's client area. If the window has a title bar, the system automatically moves it to the top of the screen or to the top of the parent window's client area. Also, the system disables the window's sizing border and the window-positioning capability of the title bar so that the user cannot move the window by dragging the title bar.
> >
> > **Minimized:** The minimized window style. By default, the system reduces a minimized window to the size of its taskbar button and moves the minimized window to the taskbar.
> >
> > **Normal:**   The normal, visible window style. The system displays a window with Normal style on the screen, in a default location. If a window is visible, the user can supply input to the window and view the window's output. Frequently, an application may initialize a new window to the Hidden style while it customizes the window's appearance, and then make the window style Normal.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
prc.StartInfo.FileName = windir + @"\explorer.exe";
prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
```

**NOTE:** *Namespace for ProcessWindowStyle* :  **`System.Diagnostics`**

Here is the complete code I used:

```
string myDocspath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string windir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR");
System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
prc.StartInfo.FileName = windir + @"\explorer.exe";
prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
prc.StartInfo.Arguments = myDocspath;
prc.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
```